# ReactJS - how to get firebase result and pass down to sub component properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have some records in the firebase, this code is to fetch it and put the result to a subcomponent. Here's the code

```
import React from "react";

export default class Home extends React.Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        this.firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://sweltering-heat-7923.firebaseio.com/contact');
        this.firebaseRef.once("value", function (snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                console.log(data.val());
            });
        });
    }
    render(){ 
        return(
            <List />
        )
    }
}

class List extends React.Component{
    render(){ 
        return(
            <div class="row">
                // populate props from Home component
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What I don't how to do is passing the response data to sub component which is List in this case.

And the firebase data look like this:

```
object {
    id:12131323, 
    firstName:'john', 
    address: {steet:'some street', city:'havana'}
}
object {
    id:12221232, 
    firstName:'joe', 
    address:{steet:'big street', city:'dubai'}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for populating that list with some items. 
slight modifications of your code:

```
class Home extends React.Component{


constructor(props) { 
super(props);
    this.state = { 
    items: [],  
    }
/// must set initial state, because this is being passed as a prop
}
componentWillMount(){

    const self = this;
    const url = 'https://sweltering-heat-7923.firebaseio.com/contact';
    this.firebaseRef = new Firebase(url);
    this.firebaseRef.once("value", function (snapshot){

// update state with new items
// which will cause re-rendering of <List> with the new items.
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            self.setState({
                items: self.state.items.concat(data.val())
            })

        });
    });


}
render(){ 
    return(
        <List items = { this.state.items } />
    )
    }
}
```

and List would look something like this:

```
const List = (props) => {


    return (
        <ul>
        { props.items.map( (item,i) => { 

         const { firstName, id } = item;
         const address = item.address.street + ', ' + item.address.city;

         return (

         <li key = { i } >
         <div>{ id }</div>
        <div> { name } </div>
        <div> { address}  </div>
         </li>
         )


        })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

what happens here is:

1) setting initial state of app with an empty array called `items`

2) updating state with new items by adding them to the `items` array

3) passing the `items` array to the List component,  as a value to a prop called `items` `<List items = { items } />`,

4) mapping over the value of the prop `items` to render the actual items.

Hope this helps!